# Auto suggest text box using PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to do an auto suggest text box using PHP and jQuery however, all the jQuery I am using, basing on the internet has already deprecated. I am not sure if my code is the one not working or the jQuery. Could anyone help me please? :) Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Autocomplete Plugin</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function() {
        $("#users").autocomplete("autoCompleteMain.php", {
          width: 260,
          matchContains: true,
          selectFirst: false
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="banner">Autocomplete</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <form autocomplete="off">
        <p>
          Enter Username <label>:</label>
          <input type="text" name="users" id="users" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="aaaa"; // Mysql password
$db_name="maptemp"; // Database name

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die(mysql_error());

$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
$sql = "select username from users where username LIKE '%$q%'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
  $cname[] = $row['username'];
}

echo json_encode($cname);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
```

**with**

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
```

because as i know `jQuery` auto Complete pass term.

Comment: @user2216351 can you please update your question with latest code..?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your array in your PHP script : `$cname = array();`

And as Dipesh Parmar said, jQuery uses "term" parameter.

Comment: What happend if you directly access the PHP script ? like http://youdomain/autoCompleteMain.php?term=something that exists in your db. Does it returns a valid json object ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to encode the result in JSON otherwise at front have you parse it. so make a html in php and echo it so you get result in html format.